# Find the number of consecutive days that users are regularly active on MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to find last the number of maximum consecutive number of days for user id.

```
   userId(string)           active_date(string) Note: Today (2022-02-20)
------------------------------------------  
{ "userId": "DbdBve", "day": "2022-02-20" }
{ "userId": "DbdBve", "day": "2022-02-19" }
{ "userId": "DbdBve", "day": "2022-02-18" }
{ "userId": "DbdBve", "day": "2022-02-17" } <- Gap here | so user's been active for the last 3 days
{ "userId": "DbdBve", "day": "2022-02-15" }


userId(string)           active_date(string)
------------------------------------------  
{ "userId": "Gj6WEth", "day": "2022-02-20" }
{ "userId": "Gj6WEth", "day": "2022-02-15" } <- Gap here | so user's been active for the last 1 days
{ "userId": "Gj6WEth", "day": "2022-02-14" }
{ "userId": "Gj6WEth", "day": "2022-02-13" }
```

Comment: what version of `mongodb` are you using?

Comment: Mongodb version 5.0

Comment: Please add example documents. The tables miss data type information

Comment: Sample documents added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using mongodb v5:

first convert date to numeric value using `$toLong`

then using `$setWindowFields` extract the user active_days ranges

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eKph5XcgdU1)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "active_date": {
        "$toLong": "$active_date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$user_id",
      sortBy: {
        active_date: 1
      },
      output: {
        days: {
          $push: "$active_date",
          window: {
            range: [
              -86400000, // one day in millisecond
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "days": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$gt": [
              {
                "$size": "$days"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$user_id",
      sortBy: {
        active_date: 1
      },
      output: {
        count: {
          $sum: "$days",
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        user_id: "$user_id",
        count: "$count"
      },
      "active_days": {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "to": {
        "$max": "$active_date"
      },
      "from": {
        "$min": "$active_date"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and at the end get the latest active_day range by adding these two stages:

```
{
  "$sort": {
    to: -1
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.user_id",
    "last_active_days": {
      "$first": "$active_days"
    }
  }
}
```

---

older versions of mongodb using `$reduce`

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kGDIApO5eFZ)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      active_date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$user_id",
      dates: {
        "$push": {
          "$toLong": "$active_date"
        },
        
      },
      from: {
        $first: {
          "$toLong": "$active_date"
        }
      },
      to: {
        $last: {
          "$toLong": "$active_date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      active_days: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            result: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$dates",
                initialValue: {
                  prev: {
                    $subtract: [
                      "$from",
                      86400000
                    ]
                  },
                  range: {
                    from: "$from",
                    to: 0,
                    count: 0
                  },
                  ranges: []
                },
                in: {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $subtract: [
                            "$$this",
                            "$$value.prev"
                          ]
                        },
                        86400000
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      prev: "$$this",
                      range: {
                        from: "$$value.range.from",
                        to: "$$value.range.to",
                        count: {
                          $add: [
                            "$$value.range.count",
                            1
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      ranges: "$$value.ranges"
                    },
                    {
                      ranges: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                          "$$value.ranges",
                          [
                            {
                              from: "$$value.range.from",
                              to: "$$value.prev",
                              count: "$$value.range.count"
                            }
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      range: {
                        from: "$$this",
                        to: "$to",
                        count: 1
                      },
                      prev: "$$this"
                    },
                    
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$result.ranges",
              [
                "$$result.range"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      active_days: {
        "$last": "$active_days.count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Do you have any solution for Mongodb v4?

Comment: added to answer @Laakal

Comment: Thanks @1sina1. Is it find from today?

Comment: sorry didn't get what you mean

Comment: Suppose today is 2022-02-20 and any user was active from the 2022-02-18. so the result is zero.

Comment: filter active_date at first? check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8l9cf1Qce3L)

Comment: Awesome! If I want to count every distinct date only once, I replace `$push` for `$addToSet`?

Comment: @FlorianWalther no `$addToSet` won't guarantee the order so you might get wrong answer, you can group by date and remove the duplicates, something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zb-0vSEfXWg)

Comment: @1sina1 Thank you for the help! What if I have a `sortBy` before the `$addToSet`? Doesn't this solve the order problem?

Comment: @FlorianWalther we already sort before `$addToSet`, the problem is the when you add items to array using `$addToSet` the order might change, another solution is to sort array after `$addToSet`